# Login for ASP.NET MVC 5 unit test is failing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am using the below code to test for login in, and I am getting 3 errors.

1. AccountController has some invalid arguments.
2. I cannot convert from AuthProvider to ApplicationUserManager.
3. Cannot implicitly convert type

   **System.Threading.Tasks.Task to System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult**

   ```
   [TestMethod]
   public void CanLoginWithValidCredentials() {

       // Arrange - create a mock authentication provider
       Mock<IAuthProvider> mock = new Mock<IAuthProvider>();
       mock.Setup(m => m.Authenticate("admin", "secret")).Returns(true);

       // Arrange - create the view model
       LoginViewModel model = new LoginViewModel {
           UserName = "admin",
           Password = "secret"
       };

       // Arrange - create the controller
       AccountController target = new AccountController(mock.Object);

       // Act - authenticate using valid credentials
       ActionResult result = target.Login(model, "/MyURL");

       // Assert
       Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(RedirectResult));
       Assert.AreEqual("/MyURL", ((RedirectResult)result).Url);
   }
   ```

Here is my login controller:

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    public AccountController()
    {
    }

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
    }

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

    //
    // GET: /Account/Login
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Please help out.